# I can't save "always run as administrator" setting

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to run Steam as "Administrator" and "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)" compatibility mode.
Whenever I check these settings and click Apply, then OK, when I check again in Properties they are unchecked again.

I've surfed the Internet for answers with no success.

Comment: If you're on a domain your domain controller could be blocking you from saving settings on logoff.

Comment: This is my PC and i'm supposed to be on the one and only Administrator Account

Comment: OK. Are you using the built-in administrator account? If not, try logging into that and see if it has the same problem. If it's not enabled, enter this into CMD: `net user Administrator /active:yes`

Comment: If you're trying to apply it directly to an EXE perhaps try creating a shortcut to it, and then apply the Always Run as Admin to the shortcut.

Comment: Creating a shortcut doesn't help, settings still won't save
Also i did the "net user Administrator /active:yes" in CMD
but nothing changed
still won't save them.. i figured it's just a thing with steam but i would still like to run it as an admin

Comment: You have to log out then log into the admin account.

Comment: this is the one and only account this PC has, and it's the administrator account

Comment: Isn't XP always running everything with Administrator privileges if your account has them? UAC was introduced in Vista. (btw, you should upgrade)

Comment: I have Windows 7

Comment: I don't know why but someone edited my question making it say i have windows XP

Comment: "Windows Service Pack 3" is XP (SP3)... i didn't change it but your question text and tags don't match up

Comment: you know in properties when you select compatibility there's a setting that goes "Run this program in compatibility mode for: Windows Service pack 3" that's the one i mean i still have Windows 7 tho.
There i edited it, should be more understandable now